# Unable to send email __Connection Refused Error

Tags: python, email

```
import smtplib

sender = 'user@gmail.com'
receivers = ['user_2@gmail.com']

message = """From: User <user@gmail.com>
To: To user_2 <user_2@gmail.com>
Subject: message
this is a test megssage.
"""

try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
    print ("Successfully sent email")
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

When I try to run this program, it shows an error:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Moreover what do I have to put in `localhost`?

Comment: Easy on the bold. Code or errors are shown with 4 spaces before the line, and `inline code` surrounded by `.

Comment: Are you able to ping the destination first?

Comment: you might have to say hello before sending mail.  `smtpObj.ehlo()`

Comment: may help you..https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/issues/167

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in gmail **Allow less secure apps** is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

I think in your local machine your own smtp server is not running. instead of using your own smtp server (localhost) try this:-

**smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)**